# tableView.dequeueReusableCell() inside of tableRow(_:heightForRowAt:) method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to have a specific height for each `table view` `cell` I have. The height depends on the content (= the height of a `UITextField` inside the `cell`).

To calculate its height, I want to create a "prototypeCell" and add the text to it to get the needed height. That's the only thing I need this created cell for. I tried this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        let entry = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)

        guard !entry.isFault else { // some entries are faults, somehow
            return 0
        }

        let prototypeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "bitCell") as! BitCell
        prototypeCell.configure(entry: entry) // add text and stuff

        // .cellContentHeight calculates the height I need for the cell
        return prototypeCell.cellContentHeight + baseRowHeight
    }
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. I skip all `entry`objects that are faults (there are quite a few of them when I open the app with the table view). Does this have any negative impact?
2. Can I use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell()` within this method? As I understand it, it dequeues an existing cell and creates a new one. But I kind of dump this cell afterwards. Is this bad?

If you need any more code, tell me. I'm not sure, what's needed to answer this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never call `tableView.dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Is there another way to get the `cell`with the identifier "bitCell"? I tried using the init of the `BitCell()` class but it does not work

Comment: check this out instead: https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: I will take a look into this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create class method in your UITableViewCell file and pass text to this method and get back CGFloat for cell height .
I write this method for my cell with label but you can use it with UITextField if you need

```
class func suggestedHeight(text:String) -> CGFloat{
    let label = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - LABEL_LEFT_AND_RIGHT_PADDING,1))
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Regular", size: 14)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return TOP_PADDING + label.frame.height
}
```

Then in heightForRow

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let entry = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
    return BitCell.suggestedHeight(text:entry)
}
```

Comment: great idea! I only had to estimate `LABEL_LEFT_AND_RIGHT_PADDING` but that's noch difficult as I have constraints that make it possible to calculate the exact padding. Thanks!